# Can Python SDK Register JS Client for Firebase Events?

Tags: javascript, python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using only the Real-Time Database part of Firebase.

I have a Python Firebase admin on the server, a Javascript Firebase on the web client.  No Android or iOS.  My web Javascript client receives a token from the Python server for its authentication.

Only the Python server writes to Firebase, the Javascript client never does. But the client registers a "child_added" listener with Firebase to receive database changes in data.

**Everything works except for this event listener.**

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) say:

> The Python Admin SDK currently only supports blocking reads. It cannot
>   be used to add event listeners that receive realtime update
>   notifications.

But as I understand it, that applies to my server, not the client.  Or **does getting a custom token from a Python Admin disqualify the Javascript client for these events?**

Maybe it's a problem that the server initializes itself with service account credentials, while the client does so with an api key?  If so, why doesn't Firebase issue an error?

Here's the relevant Python code (views.py):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, db

def getFirebaseInstance():
  try:
    # using fresh download of key from service account for this app
    cred = credentials.Certificate('myapp/static/myap/firebase/firebase-adminsdk-4mcup-144fd3c404.json')
    firebase = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'databaseURL': 'https://my-db-url'})
  except:
    raise

@login_required()
def firebaseClientToken(request):
  try:
    global __firebase
    if __firebase is None:
      __firebase = getFirebaseInstance()
    token = firebase_admin.auth.create_custom_token('1')
    return HttpResponse(token)
  except Exception as err:
    return HttpResponse("System error:" + str(err), status=406)


def sendToFirebase(request, data):
  try:
    global __firebase
    if not __firebase:
      __firebase = getFirebaseInstance()
    db = firebase_admin.db
    ref = db.reference("messages/")
    ref.push(json.dumps(data))
  except Exception:
     raise
```

All that works fine as far as the server being able to write to firebase and for generating a custom Token.

The javascript web client receives a token from the Python server (not shown), and registers the event listener with:

```
(
function authClient2Firebase() {
    var waiting;

    $.ajax({
        url: "firebaseClientToken/",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) { step2(response); },
        error: function(xhr) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
   });


    function step2(customToken) {
        try {           
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                alert(errorMessage + ' code:' + errorCode);
            }); 
            var db = firebase.database();
            var fbRef = db.ref("myapp");
            fbRef.startAt(loadTransaction.time).on ( "child_added", 
function(snapshot) { alert(snapshot.val()); });
        }
    }
}
)();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with tokens or authentication at all, but with a difference between the push(data) command in the Firebase Python and Javascript SDK vs. their documentation.

See the accepted answer at:
[Why does Firebase event return empty object on second and subsequent events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219972/why-does-firebase-event-return-empty-object-on-second-and-subsequent-events)