# Why does Firebase event return empty object on second and subsequent events?

Tags: python, events, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Python Firebase SDK on the server, which writes to Firebase real-time DB.

I have a Javascript Firebase client on the browser, which registers itself as a listener for "child_added" events.

Authentication is handled by the Python server.

With Firebase rules allowing reads, the client listener gets data on the first event (all data at that FB location), but only a key with empty data on subsequent child_added events.

Here's the listener registration:

```
firebaseRef.on
    (
      "child_added",
      function(snapshot, prevChildKey)
      {
        console.log("FIREBASE REF: ", firebaseRef);
        console.log("FIREBASE KEY: ", snapshot.key);
        console.log("FIREBASE VALUE: ", snapshot.val());
      }
    );
```

"REF" is always good.

"KEY" is always good.

But "VALUE" is empty after the first full retrieval of that db location.

I tried instantiating the firebase reference each time anew inside the listen function.  Same result.

I tried a "value" event instead of "child_added".  No improvement.

The data on the Firebase side looks perfect in the FB console.

Here's how the data is being written by the Python admin to firebase:

```
def push_value(rootAddr, childAddr, data):
  try:
    ref = db.reference(rootAddr)
    posts_ref = ref.child(childAddr)
    new_post_ref = posts_ref.push()
    new_post_ref.set(data)
  except Exception:
    raise
```

And as I said, this works perfectly to put the data at the correct place in FB.

Why the empty event objects after the first download of the database, on subsequent events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  Like most things, it turned out to be simple, but took a couple of days to find.  Maybe this will save someone else.

On the docs page:
http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push

> "In JavaScript and Python, the pattern of calling push() and then
>   immediately calling set() is so common that the Firebase SDK lets you
>   combine them by passing the data to be set directly to push() as
>   follows..."

I suggest the wording should emphasize that you **must** do it that way.

The earlier Python example on the same page doesn't work:

```
new_post_ref = posts_ref.push()
new_post_ref.set({
    'author': 'gracehop',
    'title': 'Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language'
})
```

A separate empty push() followed by set(data) as in this example, won't work for Python and Javascript because in those cases the push() implicitly also does a set() and so an empty push triggers unwanted event listeners with empty data, and the set(data) didn't trigger an event with data, either.

In other words, the code in the question:

```
new_post_ref = posts_ref.push()
new_post_ref.set(data)
```

must be:

```
new_post_ref = posts_ref.push(data)
```

with set() not explicitly called.

Since this push() code happens only when new objects are written to FB, the initial download to the client wasn't affected.

Though the documentation may be trying to convey the evolution of the design, it fails to point out that only the last Python and Javascript example given will work and the others shouldn't be used.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me, .push shouldn't call set() with empty params and goes against their whole design / docs